# Seperators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I am asking the user to input a string with a readLine function and I would like to then split that string into characters. Is there any other separator for the split function than "" which only splits into strings?

Here is my code

```
var word = readLine("Enter your word (all lowercase):");
var crtLtrs = word.split(" ");
println(crtLtrs);
```

Comment: The concept of a "word" varies a lot across languages. The basic JavaScript string functions know nothing about that.

Comment: Do you mean `word.split('')`?

Comment: The concept of a "character" is also variable, so `split('')` might or might not produce sensible results in all languages.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need split string;

you can loop through it just by index

but if you want to split just use **""** not space

```js
var word = "Enter your word (all lowercase):";
var crtLtrs = word.split("");
console.log(crtLtrs);

/* result
[
  "E",
  "n",
  "t",
  "e",
  "r",
  " ",
  "y",
  "o",
  "u",
  "r",
  " ",
  "w",
  "o",
  "r",
  "d",
  " ",
  "(",
  "a",
  "l",
  "l",
  " ",
  "l",
  "o",
  "w",
  "e",
  "r",
  "c",
  "a",
  "s",
  "e",
  ")",
  ":"
] */

// example 2

var word2 = "Enter your word (all lowercase):";
console.log(word2[0])
console.log(word2[1]);
```

Comment: This is no more reliable for complex characters such as [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#In_Unicode) or compound vowel diacritics